# Custom Date Locale in Excell

Tags: microsoft-excel, date, locale

Does anyone know where the date locales are stored in Excel?  I would love to be able to create a custom format (a copy of the gregorian calendar, but with different month and weekday names).

Comment: I did use Microsoft's Local Builder to create my custom locale definition, and it does work when selected in windows control panel (dates are formatted properly in explorer, and such).  Even going into excel, I can then see the dates formated like this, with the new local showing up in the date format window.  Unfortunately, this format is only available when windows is selected to this new locale.  If I switch windows back to a built-in locale, excel no longer uses the custom one, and doesn't even list the custom choice in the dropdown of the date format.

Comment: I only want this custom format used in a specific few documents, so it needs to be selectable in the formatting options within excel, not dependent on windows options.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1743868/edit) instead of adding information in comments